# Changing data type of default value in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array that I want to change to a list of strings and be displayed in a text_area.  I don't know much about form helpers yet, but I'm assuming there is a way to do this without creating one since all I should have to do is send the default value to a view helper.  But I'm not seeing how this is done..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
<%= text_area_tag :text_area_name, @my_array.join("\n\r") %>
```